# How do I open a file saved in the user directory using Electron's Shell API

Tags: javascript, electron, desktop-application

I'd like an Electron app to natively open a file stored in the User directory, with the path as `%userprofile%/Documents/Dir1/ThisFile.txt`.

From Electron's [Shell Documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/shell):

```
const { shell } = require('electron')

shell.openPath('%userprofile%/Documents/Dir1/ThisFile.txt')
```

yields an error:

> Windows cannot find '%userprofile%/Documents/Dir1/ThisFile.txt'. Make sure you typed the name correctly and try again.

I have also tried using:
`shell.openPath(path.relative('./','%userprofile%/Documents/Dir1/ThisFile.txt'));` which results in the same  error.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to open a file stored in %userprofile%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use electron's cross-platform `.getPath()` method for that:

```js
const path = require("path");
const { app, shell } = require("electron");

shell.openPath(path.join(app.getPath("documents"), "Dir1", "ThisFile.txt"));
```

See here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname

Comment: Thanks. Your solution doesn't throw any error but neither does it spawn the text file. I'll do more tests to see where there's a disconnect.

Comment: @mak49 Well, `shell.openPath` doesn't create new files. You need to do that with [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

Comment: Sorry for my poor choice of words, I meant open. `const { app, shell } = require("electron").remote;` solved the disconnect.